# How to learn nsIZipWriter and nsIZipReader?

Tags: asynchronous, firefox-addon, zip

I was wondering how to use JavaScript to do async zip writing and reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for zip reading using [nsIZipReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader), zip writing goes in a similar way. The example reads a zip file from `/tmp/example.zip` and prints the content of the first file to the console.

Remarks:

- I'm using [`nsIInputStreamPump`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsIInputStreamPump.idl) for async I/O <sup>I found a reference to this API at the [Streams guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Guide/Streams#Forcing_an_input_stream_to_be_read)</sup>. This interface offers a `.asyncRead` method which takes an object that implements [`nsIStreamListener`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsIStreamListener.idl) (and [`nsIRequestObserver`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/nsIRequestObserver.idl)).
- I have compared the running time of this example with the [synchronous zip reading example at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader#List_contents_of_XPI_and_read_file_contents) and found that reading the time used by the blocking read is significantly smaller (reading a zip file from RAM disk: from 1-2ms to 0.1-0.3ms) <sup>(measured using `console.time('foo');` before the `reusableStreamInstance.init` invocation and `console.timeEnd('foo');` after `reusableStreamInstance.readBytes`)</sup>.
- I am using `.readBytes` instead of `.read` to avoid truncation of data if the file contains a null byte.
- I haven't implemented any error handling (zip not existent, zip doesn't contain a file, zip/file cannot be opened), but I do close the zipreader regardless of whether an error occurs.

```js
let { Cc: classes, Cu: utils, Ci: interfaces } = Components;

Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');

let pathToZip = '/tmp/example.zip';
let nsiFileZip = new FileUtils.File(pathToZip);

let streamListener = {
  buffer: null,
  // nsIRequestObserver
  onStartRequest: function(aRequest, aContext) {
    this.buffer = [];
  },
  // nsIStreamListener
  onDataAvailable:
      function(aRequest, aContext, aInputStream, aOffset, aCount) {
    let reusableStreamInstance = Cc['@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1']
        .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream);
    reusableStreamInstance.init(aInputStream);
    let chunk = reusableStreamInstance.readBytes(aCount);
    this.buffer.push(chunk);
  },
  // nsIRequestObserver
  onStopRequest: function(aRequest, aContext, aStatusCode) {
    console.log('end', aStatusCode);
    var data = this.buffer.join('');
    console.log(data);
  }
};

let pump = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1']
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIInputStreamPump);
let zr = Cc['@mozilla.org/libjar/zip-reader;1']
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIZipReader);
try {
  zr.open(nsiFileZip);
  // null = no entry name filter.
  var entries = zr.findEntries(null);
  while (entries.hasMore()) {
    var entryPointer = entries.getNext();
    var entry = zr.getEntry(entryPointer);
    if (!entry.isDirectory) {
      var stream = zr.getInputStream(entryPointer);
      pump.init(stream, 0, -1, 0, 0, true);
      pump.asyncRead(streamListener, null);
      // For the demo, we only take one file, so break now.
      break;
    }
  }
} finally {
  zr.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that timing test on async/sync this is reall nice thanks for all the work!!