# JavaScript: XMLHttpRequest() from Firefox addon to get zip

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, zip

I am trying to build a Firefox addon to request a zip file from a webpage and store it locally/decompress. I receive a 200 response code when I request the zip as a Blob type, but I am unsure how to store it since the Firefox file I/O documentation is quite confusing.

```
getFiles : function (version) {
  if(version != "?"){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    url = "http://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/archive/master.zip"
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';

    xmlhttp.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            // Note: .response instead of .responseText
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'compress/zip'});
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
 return zip;
},
```

[File I/O documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O)

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly what this does: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ it doesnt however decompress it. But you can do that. I would recommend async method of zip.js: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/issues/102#issuecomment-94054600 if you requesttype arraybuffer you can write the zip to desktop with os.file now to uncompress hm let me work on something

Comment: Yeah definitely look at using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm instead of the File I/O docs you linked to - they have improved both the API and docs in recent years so lots of old examples are unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost dont, I'm just stuck on figuring out how to use the asynchronus zip.js module. You can use nsIZipWriter and nsIZipReader like the linked addon does from my comment. But I think async is just better so I'm working on that:

https://github.com/Noitidart/AysncZip/blob/master/bootstrap.js

Install the addon, click on the toolbar icon, download the zip. Clicking zipped will save it a a zipped file. Clicking "Decompressed" is currently a work in progress.

Using XPCOM for zips:

- [How to learn nsIZipWriter and nsIZipReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344470/learning-nsizipwriter-and-nsizipreader) - For asyn but on-mainthread execution of reading and writing zips
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56821/improvements-to-nsizipreader-and-nsiscriptableinputstream